# Arduino Link with Arduino Yun Rev 2 (new model)

Tags: hardware

I'd like to preface this question with that I have no Arduino board experience; the ability to do it with Mathematica gives me the courage (/patience) to attempt it.  While I'm trying to ask a pointed question, I'm open to any suggestion prior to getting the ball rolling. My primary goal, as a gift to my atmospheric and air chemistry girlfriend, is automated storage and detection of time-series quantifying temperature, humidity, light intensity, etc. in-home using `DataDrop` functionality.

The Mathematica 11.3 [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/device/Arduino.html) states that it is currently compatible with the Arduino Uno and Arduino Yun board models.  However, the Arduino Yun has been discontinued in favor of its successor, the Arduino Yun Rev 2.

I called Wolfram support and they reported that, while they do not know if Mathematica 11.3 will work with the new Yun Rev 2 model, a broader microcontroller interface package that will even go beyond Arduino boards is in pre-release testing.  Some of the functionality of this package is to be integrated with the Mathematica 12 release "soon," though they couldn't specify exactly when.

Has anyone used the newer Yun Rev 2 successfully?  Alternatively, has anyone used microcontrollers other than the clearly stated models supported (Uno and Yun) that might be suited to the purpose of my little chemist ㋡?  For example, there are reports of users having variable degrees of partial success using clearly unsupported boards (the Mega2560, etc.):  either it [doesn't support basic interfacing at all](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145734/send-serial-input-to-arduino-meta2560-board) or it does, but is [recognized as the Uno board](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145485/how-to-use-the-various-pins-of-arduino-mega-2560-while-mathematica-identifies-it) with fewer channels etc. than the board actually has.  I am also interested if anyone has found ways to circumnavigate these issues, although it seems many questions are unanswered in this regard.

Comment: Please, post an update if you have any further information or have an answer to your own question. WM 12 has implemented the microcontroller function.

Comment: I have decided to go with a Raspberry Pi given it can run Mathematica itself.  As of version 12, a major microcontroller version, it still faces some issues, but the Pi seems reasonably suited to this kind of task.  Still troubleshooting, though.